# Rotated images not displaying correctly in Google Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, php, image, google-chrome, rotation

There is a list of images in client edit section, and next to each image there are 2 action buttons (delete and rotate), as shown on picture below. So the problem is that when I rotate the image, page refreshes, image rotates, but image with changed angle is not displayed with correct angle. The only way to show images correctly is to hard refresh the browser. This problem is only related to Chrome browser. It works well on other browsers.

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPCkk.png)

Here is how I managed the rotation.

HTML (I tried using timestamp next to image url, but it didn't work)

```
@if(!empty($images[0]))
    <section class="panel">
        <header class="panel-heading panel-align">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Images</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @foreach($images as $img)
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="overflow: auto;">
                <div class="popup-gallery">
                    <!-- edit timestamp is glued to link because chrome is caching images and rotated images are not shown. -->
                    <a class="pull-left mb-xs mr-xs" href="{{$img->image_url.'?'.filemtime(ltrim($img->image_url, '/'))}}" title="Images" rel="group1">
                        <div class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="{{$img->image_url}}" width="105">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#deleteImageModal" class="modal-basic mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-danger btn-delete-image" imageId="{{$img->id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                    <button type="button" class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-info btn-rotate-image" imageId="{{$img->id}}" data-param="montage"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i></button>
                </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </section>
@endif
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn-rotate-image').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('imageId');
    var param = $(this).data('param');
    $.ajax({
        method  :   'GET',
        cache   :   false,
        url     :   '/image/rotation',
        data    :   {
            'id'    :   id,
            'param' :   param
        },
        success : function(){
            document.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

});

PHP

```
public function image_rotation(Request $request){
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $param = $request->input('param');
    $imageModel = new Images();
    $url = ltrim($imageModel->get_image_url($id, $param), '/');
    $sourceImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
    $rotated = imagerotate($sourceImg, -90, 0);
    imagejpeg($rotated, $url, 100);
}
```

The code is working, it rotates the image, but after document.location.reload(); Chrome browser is not displaying image with correct angle. It's not displaying correctly if page is refreshed with F5, ctrl+R, it only works with hard refresh ctrl+shift+R.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing page caching solved the problem by adding these lines of code into the controller.

```
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```